# Php mysql - stucked with array strings - mess with the words

Tags: php, arrays

I have an application called mystique item where users has to guess the item that's behind the watermark. Water mark is revealing on time to time and everything is working perfect, but i have a "small" problem with guessing words. I have added words in arrays, separated with commas, and i'm exploding that array in my php, what i would like to know is how to make the application accept the words if user mess with them, for example, my phrase is: "apple iphone4", i would like to make it correct even if user write "iphone4 apple".

Here's the array i'm using:

```
$sp = explode(",",$gt);
$sp = array_map('trim', $sp);
if(in_array($val, $sp)) { // guess correct
    echo '1';
}
else{ // guess wrong
    echo '2';
}
```

Comment: My mysql column is like this: "apple iphone4,apple ipad,apple ipod,apple iphone5" ...

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
$sp = explode(",",$gt);
$sp = array_map('trim', $sp);
if(in_array($val, $sp)) { // guess correct
    echo '1';
}
else{ 
// and it only execute when if will fail
    foreach($sp as $value){
                 $check= array_diff(explode(" ", $val),explode(" ",$value));
        if(empty($check)){
            // above like make an array separating by space and match with so that
            // it will match "iphone4 pad" and "pad iphone4" as equal 
           //break;
        }else{

        }
    }

    // guess wrong
    //echo '2';
}
```

Comment: what error is there?, use space in second explode, update my answer

Comment: You cannot use `array_diff` in that context: `if(empty(array_diff(explode(" ", $val),explode(" ",$value))))`

Answer (score 0):

### Values

In the following `$arr` is the array equivalent to your `$sp` and `$input` is the user input equivalent to your `$val`.

### Examples

If user input is `iphone apple` then the code will match against `apple iphone`.

If the user inputs `apple iphone 4` it will also match against `apple iphone` to stop this from happening you will need to uncomment the code on lines `21` and `22`.

### Code

```
$arr = array(
    'apple iphone',
    'apple ipad',
    'apple ipod',
    'apple iphone5'
    );

$input      = 'apple iphone 4';
$inputArray = array_filter(explode(' ', $input));

$matched    = TRUE;
if(!in_array(trim($input), $arr)){
    $matched = FALSE;
    foreach($arr as $item){
        $itemMap = explode(' ', $item);
        $comparisonResult  = array_diff($itemMap, $inputArray);
        //$comparisonResult2 = array_diff($inputArray, $itemMap);
        if(empty($comparisonResult) /*&& empty($comparisonResult2)*/){
            $matched = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if($matched)
    echo 1;
else
    echo 2;
```